# Can't change recording input with Pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio

In some applications, while they may be configured to use the correct microphone, they will only record audio from the generic "analog input" input in Pulseaudio. However, changing the setting in the recording tab with pavucontrol doesn't stick. It seems to force itself to use the generic analog input. Is there a way to force this setting?

Comment: change the default input source

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: As this is very unusual behaviour, it may help to know what "some applications" are called. I just checked with `arecord`, even generic ALSA applications can be switched with `pavucontrol`. If you mean "they don't remember this setting on next start", that's a different issue - look into `module-stream-restore`.